# c# Unable to parse xml, receiving error 463

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, task

Basically I am trying to parse xml [from this](https://habbo.com/gamedata/furnidata_xml/1)  
However I recieve {"The remote server returned an error: (463)."} (System.Net.WebException) The error happens in `string xml = webClient2.DownloadString(address);`

Here is my full code

```
Task.Run((Action)(() =>
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            using (WebClient webClient1 = new WebClient())
            {
                WebClient webClient2 = webClient1;
                Uri address = new Uri("https://habbo.com/gamedata/furnidata_xml/1");
                string xml = webClient2.DownloadString(address);
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
            }
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode1 in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("furnitype"))
            {
                string nr1 = "[" + xmlNode1.Attributes["id"].Value + "]";
                string nr2 = " : " + xmlNode1.Attributes["classname"].InnerText;
                foreach (XmlNode xmlNode2 in xmlNode1)
                {
                    XmlNode childNode = xmlNode2;
                    if (childNode.Name == "name")
                    {
                        this.FurniCB.Invoke((Action)(() => this.FurniCB.Items.Add((object)(nr1 + nr2 + " : " + childNode.InnerText))));
                        this.FurniDataList.Add(nr1 + nr2 + " : " + childNode.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code's downloading part. All you need is to add `User-Agent` header to the request..

```
webClient1.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
```

Comment: OMG, I have been trying to fix this for 6 months, You saved my life ! Thanks Alot!

Comment: @Hasan if it helped, then please read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work